# Visual Studio Minimize regions shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key in Visual Studio that will minimize all of the regions or + signs so that I don't have to go through and click each one individually?

Comment: How to collapse **regions** is actually not clearly answered in any of these answers nor on the linked question. Pressing (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O) will **toggle** between collapsed or expanded state, not just 'expand all'

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
C-m, C-o // collapse all
C-m, C-l // expand all
C-m, C-m // collapse, expand one
```

Where C is short for `Ctrl`. You can find more shortcuts at the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

You can find the commands by going to Keyboard Options under the Tools menu, they are mapped to these commands

- Edit.CollapseToDefinitions (`C-m, C-o`),
- Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion (`C-m, C-m`) and
- Edit.ToggleAllOutlining (`C-m, C-l`)

[image]

---

If you are using Visual Studio Code the commands are similar but work differently. The commands are roughly these

- `C-k 2` - Fold Level 2
- `C-k C-j` - Unfold all
- `C-k [` - Unfold recursively (unfold where the caret is)

You can search for Fold or Unfold commands (using `C-S-p`) to find all of them.

Comment: To collapse actual #regions press **(Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L)** once or twice. Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 51):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd> - expand/collapse at caret
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd> - collapse all in document
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> - expand all in document

Comment: <kbd>Fancy</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

You can perform this on a selection too.

Comment: This will only minimize *one* region though, not all of them at the same time